# cv::cuda::Stream select thread default stream

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

We are compiling using `-default-stream=per-thread` to get a per thread stream for CUDA. But when we do: `cv::cuda::Stream::Null()` we get a stream pointer that points to the "legacy default stream" (see details [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/stream-sync-behavior.html#stream-sync-behavior__per-thread-default-stream)).

**How can we get a `cv::cuda::Stream` that points to the cuda stream handle `CU_STREAM_PER_THREAD`?**

More generally, how can we get a `cv::cuda::Stream` that points to an existing `cudaStream_t` handle?

Answer (score 2):

There is a friend of the `cv::cuda::Stream` [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/df1/structcv_1_1cuda_1_1StreamAccessor.html) called the `cv::cuda::StreamAccessor`. This struct has a static member function:

```
static Stream wrapStream (cudaStream_t stream)
```

which can be used as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/core/cuda_stream_accessor.hpp>
#include <cuda.h>

...

auto cvThreadDefaultStream = 
    cv::cuda::StreamAccessor::wrapStream(CU_STREAM_PER_THREAD);
```

to get a `cv` `Stream` that represents the default thread stream.